# What do you call neither spicy nor sweet food?

Tags: word-request

What do you call food without a lot of pepper or salt or spices? How is the taste of ordinary food called?

Comment: Non-sweet food is called 'savoury' food. However that can include spicy food. Bland food is food without much flavour. That can include savoury or sweet foods. As [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bland) says: > **bland** (*adj.*) lacking a strong or particular flavor

Comment: The *trap* here is - neither spicy nor ***sweet!***

Comment: bland or dull I'm only not sure about using it for food stuff

Comment: It's kind of weird to oppose spicy to sweet. The opposite of sweet is savory.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Such food is *unseasoned*:

> a : not seasoned with added spices or savory ingredients
>   // *unseasoned* food

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unseasoned))

If you want to emphasize a lack of flavor, you can use the word *bland*:

> 2 c : lacking strong flavor
>   // Expect both kinds of salsify to be subtle and delicate—too *bland* for some tastebuds.

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bland))

Comment: Important usage note: if you tell a cook that their food is bland, it could be taken as an insult.

Comment: Also, plain mustard greens not seasoned are spicy and plain apples (most) not seasoned are sweet.

Answer (score 17):

Food  that is **simple**,  not rich, spicy nor particularly sweet or salty is sometimes said to be **plain**. Plain food does not mean it is without salt, flavourings or sugar; plain simple cooking is the type of food one eats at home, and is suitable for both savoury and sweet food.

Plain yoghurt
Plain fish and chips
Plain potato soup
Plain sponge cake.

From [Cambridge Dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/plain)

> - He prefers **plain food** - nothing too fancy.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/plain)

> - ‘Yet, perhaps because he deals mainly with sophisticated food, he prefers **plain cooking** at home.’
> - ‘He liked **plain food**, without sauces or cheese, and plenty of fresh vegetables, including those grown in the garden of his estate.’

From  [FRAZE.IT](https://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?hardm=1&t=0&l=0&p=4&q=plain)

> - Either way, a dollop of sour cream or **plain Greek-style yogurt** is a fine finish
> - **Plain rice and water**, with 12-hour days, 7 days a week, of hard physical labour
> - Scatter the top with more raspberries and grated **plain chocolate** before serving.

Answer (score 5):

The first problem here is that your question is somewhat ambiguous, because (at least in US English) spicy has two distinct meanings.  It can be either something that is flavored with traditional spices like cinnamon, cloves, ginger, nutmeg &c, or it can be something that contains (often to excess) chili pepper.

Beyond that, there really isn't a single word that covers all sorts of unspiced foods, since there are so many differently-flavored "ordinary" foods, many of which have strong flavors that aren't the result of either sort of spice - e.g. chocolate, some kinds of cheeses, many fruits.

"Bland" doesn't really fit, since it just means that the food doesn't have strong flavors, regardless of whether that lack is innate to the food itself (as for instance mashed potatos), or because it wasn't spiced.

Comment: "Spicy" in the "hot" sense can also come from ingredients other than chili pepper, like mustard, ginger, or wasabi.

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 'flavours' or tastes. They are sweetness, sourness, bitterness, saltiness and umami  (all are self explanatory, except Umami, which is described as savory and is characteristic of broths and cooked meats. (a bit like Marmite?)

Comment: Yes. We had to borrow *umami* from Japanese, because "savoury" was too vague to be applied to a specific taste detected by none of the other taste sensors and IIRC, related specifically to glutamates. Marmite, also much far Eastern cooking using fermented bean or fish sauces.

Answer (score -2):

[**Unseasoned**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unseasoned)

Meaning:

> not seasoned with added spices or savory ingredients

[**Low Sodium Diet**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/low-sodium%20diet)

Meaning:

> a diet restricted to foods naturally low in sodium content and prepared without added salt that is used especially in the management of hypertension, heart failure, and kidney or liver dysfunction

(Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/)

Comment: You should quote the definitions from those links within your answer itself. (Also, Google isn't really a reliable source for definitions, so you may want to link to Merriam-Webster or something for "unseasoned".) Your answer should stand on its own as an answer to the question. More specifically, you should point out how these definitions match what OP is asking for; I'm not sure how "low-sodium", on its own, has anything to do with taste (other than that products are sometimes advertised as "low-sodium" when they have less salt - but that doesn't make "low-sodium" mean bland/unseasoned).

Comment: @V2blast Medical Definition of low-sodium diet

: a diet restricted to foods naturally low in sodium content and prepared without added salt that is used especially in the management of hypertension, heart failure, and kidney or liver dysfunction.

Comment: Unseasoned :not seasoned with added spices or savory ingredientsunseasoned food

Comment: Rather than replying to me, you should edit your answer to read as if it were always the best version of itself. See Glorfindel's answer to this question for an example of the format you may want to use. (See also [this question on meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/how-useful-are-references-and-should-their-usage-be-more-encouraged-on-ell) and [ColleenV's answer there](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3231/29690) regarding supporting answers - especially to [word-request] questions - with citations/sources.)

Comment: Low sodium is the word which is used mostly by gym freak people, but when you go to any resturant and want to order a food without any seasoning on it,you say i want ______food without any seasoning and when you go to a friend's party and you feel the taste of the food is not matching up with your tastebud,you say the food flavour is bit faded, so inshort for different occasion or scenario you use different word structure

Comment: @V2Blast thanks for suggestion

Comment: Salt is neither spicy nor sweet, so I'm not sure how that one answers the question at all.

Comment: @John Montgomery, please read the question i.e asked from the source

Comment: @RajatKrishnan I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say there. But "low sodium" doesn't necessarily imply anything about flavor at all, much less spiciness or sweetness (both of which have almost nothing to do with sodium content).

Comment: @John Montgomery ok lets make it easier to understand,what if anyone ask you to suggest them a food which is high in protein offcourse you will tell them eggs,pulses etc

Comment: @RajatKrishnan That still has absolutely nothing to do with the question. It's asking about flavor, not nutrition.

Comment: @John Montgomery ok may be then you can ignore my answer if you are not getting it because what i knew as per my knowledge i delivered it,now it may be acceptable to someone and may not be

Comment: @John Montgomery look the question is what is the food called without a lot of pepper or salt or spices? So such kind of diet is called Low Sodium Diet(which does not have much of salt content in it)

Comment: @RajatKrishnan Low sodium food can still have spices in it. It can still have sodium substitutes that taste salty. And the question isn't asking anything at all about diets, low sodium or otherwise.